# NSMakeCollectable and ARC doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to convert my old project to ARC. I have a function which creates UUIDs, but apparently this is no longer supported when using ARC:

```
NSString *uuid = nil;
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    if (theUUID) {
        uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
        //[uuid autorelease];
        CFRelease(theUUID);
    }
```

I get the compiler error (when trying to convert): 'NSMakeCollectable' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode.

So my question is: how do I create UUIDs when using ARC? Is there another way which I should now use?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`NSMakeCollectable()` is for the benefit of the (essentially deprecated) Objective-C garbage collector. ARC knows nothing about it.

You must use a special casting attribute, usually `__bridge_transfer`, to ensure that the memory is not leaked. `__bridge_transfer` is used like so:

```
id MakeUUID(void) {
    id result = nil;
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    if (uuid) {
        result = (__bridge_transfer id)uuid; // this "transfers" a retain from CF's control to ARC's control.
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit**: As other answers have mentioned, `CFBridgingRelease()` does this for you. So instead of using `(__bridge_transfer id)uuid`, it may be cleaner to write `CFBridgingRelease(uuid)`. They are equivalent though, so it's up to you which you find more readable.

Answer (score 9):

When you transfer the object from `CFString` to `NSString`, you need to let ARC know how you want to handle memory management. In this case I would suggest:

```
uuid = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
```

This instructs CoreFoundation to release the object (as is required to balance `Create`). Cocoa will ARC-retain the object when it is assigned to `uuid`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);

NSString *s2ndUuid = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID);
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a single UUID across whole app, I think the best way to achieve that would be to have it run once in the whole application lifecycle.

```
static NSString *uuid;
- (NSString *)theCurrentDeviceUniqueIdentifier {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        if (theUUID) {
            uuid = CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
            CFRelease(theUUID);
        }
    });

    return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it's definition of NSMakeCollectable

```
NS_INLINE id NSMakeCollectable(CFTypeRef cf) {
   return cf ? (id)CFMakeCollectable(cf) : nil;
}
```

I think this should work

```
uuid =CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID);
```

Comment: This will leak UUID since it has an extra `CFRetain` attached from the `Create` call.

Comment: you can use CFRelease to release

Comment: CFRelease what? You've assigned it to an ARC `id`, which can no longer be handed directly to `CFRelease()`. You could cast it back again, but that's fighting ARC. This is what `CFBridgingRelease()` and the equivalent `__bridge_transfer` are built to address.