# Issue with NSMakeCollectable when converting to ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert my code to ARC and I have problem with NSMakeCollectable in the ASIRequest library.

```
- (NSString*)encodeURL:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = NSMakeCollectable([(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])) autorelease]);
    if (newString) {
        return newString;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

It is giving me this error: `NSMakeCollectable is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting`.

How do I solve this? Need some guidance. Thanks.

EDIT:
Tried this and not working:

```
 - (NSString*)encodeURL:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString *newString = NSMakeCollectable([(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])) autorelease]);
        if (newString) {
            return (__bridge_transfer NSString*)newString;
        }
        return @"";
    }
```

Tried this as well:

```
- (NSString*)encodeURL:(NSString *)string
        {
            NSString *newString = NSMakeCollectable([(__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])) autorelease]);
            if (newString) {
                return newString;
            }
            return @"";
        }
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594721/nsmakecollectable-and-arc-doesnt-work

Comment: tried it.. not working...

Comment: not working... i edited my question..

Comment: your are changing the wrong line, if you read the links carefully you will see that the function `NSMakeCollectable` is not available when using ARC, that's the line you has to modify, no the return

Comment: edited the question again. have a look...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSMakeCollectable` is no longer required in ARC. You can use `CFBridgingRelease` here.

```
- (NSString*)encodeURL:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])));
    // or  NSString *newString = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding]));
    if (newString) {
        return newString;
    }
    return @"";
}
```