# Converting old project to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

The following code is a snippet from an older file that I'm trying to use in a newer project. Since ARC is now used, I'm having some trouble making it ARC friendly. I already got rid of all the autoreleases, but this one problem still remains. What do I replace NSMakeCollecatble with?

```
NSString *newString = NSMakeCollectable(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])));
```

Comment: See first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594721/nsmakecollectable-and-arc-doesnt-work Gives you the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198145/1835155

```
NSString *newString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding([self stringEncoding])));
```

Comment: My apologies, I found similar things, but not that one.

Comment: If you could accept the answer that'd be nice though!

Comment: 2 more minutes until I can accept.