# Check if UDID is real

Tags: ios, udid

How can I check if the iphone/ipad UDID is real device using web-service?

To explain that, i need to send UDID to my webservice to as a user id, but I need to avoid any fake UDID.

Please tell me how can we can make that possible?

Comment: Have a look to that post, that may help you for the dev of your app ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305761/4662531

Comment: If you are aware of UDID, then you must be knowing how to get that. And that **can never be fake**.

Comment: @RomOne  the idea is how can you decide if this "4f526010b044ea367baa46e9160e1319889b4b22" is real UDID or not ?

Comment: As @Nitish highlighted, if you know how to get the UDID from the device, that one can't be wrong. What you what, is some kind of security check on your server maybe? Well I'm not sure if Apple provide any sort of way to check UDID. Pretty sure they will never do.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of security matter. I know how to get UDID, but anyone can generate fake UDID.

Comment: @Pang sorry, by mistake. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know if any UDID is "real" or not on your server.

You want to look into secure authentication procedures where the UDID is used as a key to generate a hash that is exchanged.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I hope apple will open that one day :)

Comment: @DeveloperSofar If you like my answer, please click the checkmark acknowledging it.